# Removing event listener still fires when another element is hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-hover

I'm not sure if I truly understand it, and perhaps its in the third parameter ,[options] setting that I'm not fully understanding, but I'll get straight to the code.

Upon construction of the document, I want to add event listeners to handle keyup and keydowns.  I have this all working and it works great.

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', keyinputhandler, false);
window.addEventListener('keyup', keyinputhandler, false);
function keyinputhandler(e) {
//doing stuff with it here
}
```

The problem lies later on when I do something using jquery's hover method.

```
var someotherelement = $('#someotherelement');
someotherelement.hover(function(){
    window.removeEventListener('keydown', keyinputhandler, false);
    window.removeEventListener('keyup', keyinputhandler, false);
    //for some reason, the events in keyinputhandler keep firing here, why?
    }, function () {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', keyinputhandler, false);
    window.addEventListener('keyup', keyinputhandler, false);
    }
);
```

In my code above I included a comment area of what I'm trying to achieve.  When I hover a specific element, I don't want the other event handler to trigger.  How can I disable the behavior of keyinputhandler when someotherelement is hovered?

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a fiddle , or similar of your problem?  It makes it much easier for someone to help.

Comment: Will make one up for you, give just a few minutes.

Comment: As i can test it, your code works as expected. Check that if for some reason when you keydown you didn't fire mouseleave event on this element.

Comment: But I think he wants to re-attach, once the mouse leaves the element.

Comment: I think he means it's still firing while in mouse over.  The events should only be getting re-attached on mouse out.

Comment: We don't need a "fiddle". You need to put all relevant code that provides a minimal reproduction of the issue directly in the question.

Comment: ...right now there's no issue shown in your code, so there's no answerable question.

Comment: Another way to do this is to set a global variable in the hover handlers, and check the variable in the key input handler.

Comment: I would like to apologize to all as my problem was actually in what was occuring server side.  Client side behavior is as intended with event listener attaching and detaching as in my example, and the answer below by Codeicus.  If there is an admin looking at this question, kindly remove it or refrain from additional responses.

Answer (score -1):

Could you make sure that the first callback is executing? The jQuery "hover" function attaches the first callback as a listener to the "mouseenter" event.

Maybe this helps (from http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/):

> The mouseenter event differs from mouseover in the way it handles event bubbling. If mouseover were used in this example, then when the mouse pointer moved over the Inner element, the handler would be triggered. This is usually undesirable behavior. The mouseenter event, on the other hand, only triggers its handler when the mouse enters the element it is bound to, not a descendant. So in this example, the handler is triggered when the mouse enters the Outer element, but not the Inner element.

You are attaching a listener to the window object. Then, you are attaching another listener to an inner element. I think that is the problem, because of the mouseenter bubbling behaviour.

Could you try this?

```
$( "#someotherelement" )
    .mouseover(function() {
        window.removeEventListener('keydown', keyinputhandler, false);
        window.removeEventListener('keyup', keyinputhandler, false);
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
        window.addEventListener('keydown', keyinputhandler, false);
        window.addEventListener('keyup', keyinputhandler, false);
});
```

Comment: This should be left as a comment, not an answer. You may comment when you earn enough rep. Until then, please don't use an answer to dialog with the OP.

Comment: I made a clarification.

Comment: This has the same effect as my code above.  No difference (from what I can see).

Comment: this was mine I made for reference, and it is working as intended, but thank you Codeicus:

https://jsfiddle.net/L46mzb43/

Comment: @Codeicus: You've misunderstood the text you quoted. The `mouseover` and `mouseout` events are the ones that bubble, not `mouseenter/leave`. The `mouseover/out` are definitely not the way to go here.